# Why not returning full value on Laravel -Guzzle

Tags: json, laravel, guzzle

I am trying to return the JSON data from a third party API with Laravel-Guzzle. Everything is working but the value is different it's like some kind missing characters specially on images.

Here's Laravel-Guzzle code :

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

$request = $client->request('GET', 
    'https://targetweb.com/api/v2/search_items/?', [
            'query' => [
                'by' => 'relevancy',
                'keyword' => 'productx',
                'limit' => 50,
                'newest' => 0,
                'order' => 'desc',
                'page_type' => 'search',
                'version' => 2
            ]
        ]);

$array = json_decode($request->getBody()->getContents(), true);


$nArrItems = count($array['items']);
   for ($x=0;$x<$nArrItems;$x++){
       echo $array['items'][$x]['name'].'<br/>';
       $nImages = count($array['items'][$x]['images']);
       for($z=0;$z<$nImages;$z++){
           echo $array['items'][$x]['images'][$z]."<br/>";
       }

    }
```

#### Result on my browser running Laravel

[image: Result on my browser running Laravel]

It has same result as with API tester

#### Result API tester

[image: Result API tester]

but if I compare it(the above) with chrome inspect

#### Chrome inspect

[image: Chrome inspect]

> in my browser : "309adc074bfeef9ad6d13561ef2","70eb....
> in API tester : "images":["309adc074bfeef9ad6d13561ef2","70eb....
> in Chrome inspect : "images":["309adc074bfeef9ad6d13561ef2e3ad1","70eb....

It has missing characters that does not show in my browser & API Tester.

Any help as why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: welcome to so, can you show a sample on how you recieve the data, especially how you receive the images

Comment: by inspect on div image then if i browse this url https://targetweb.com/file/309adc074bfeef9ad6d13561ef2 its not show image just blank but if i browse this one https://targetweb.com/file/309adc074bfeef9ad6d13561ef2e3ad1 its show image. the problem is why guzzle can't show full value .. why its have to missing '...e3ad1' ?

Comment: is this id received as string or it is in an image, how do you recieve the id

Comment: you can use stream to get data continously until the whole data in recieved instead of recieving in packets

Comment: have you tried stream did it work out?